# In anylogic, how to add custom parameters for a single agent in the inject() function in pedSource

Tags: properties, anylogic, agent, inject

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ6rh.png)

In anylogic, how to add custom parameters for a single agent in the inject() function in pedSource

Comment: In anylogic, I set a pedSource, of course, I used the inject() function to achieve data injection, I set a property in the agent, now I require each injected agent to have the specified The attribute value, however, the inject() function is just injection, there is no way to attach the attribute I specified, this is the code, I hope some experts can explain how to deal with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the agent details in the "exit" code box using the `ped` keyword:
[image]

Alternatively, switch the "add pedestrians to" option to "custom population" and adjust the ped values there.

Or you call some code in the Ped agent type on startup code box...

Comment: Thank you for the hint, it gave me a lot of inspiration. The inject() method is just injection. In the exit method of pedSource, you can set custom properties for the current ped.