# Anylogic insert agent with variable values

Tags: anylogic, agent

One can create a new agent with the `source.inject(1)` function. Can I give this agent, while creating it, a variable value e.g. a destination?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In anylogic, how to add custom parameters for a single agent in the inject() function in pedSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72357540/in-anylogic-how-to-add-custom-parameters-for-a-single-agent-in-the-inject-fun)

Comment: But could I give every agent I create a specific variable (or parameter) value, e.g. the first created agent goes to place X and the agent created second goes to place Z? In the example you showed, all the agents receive the same parameter.

Comment: Sure, write a function that takes the creation number as an argument and returns a location. Call that from the source field

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks! How do I get the creation number?

Comment: Make a counter where you call the `inject(1)` method. Add 1 every time and use that

Comment: @Benjamin, That was a bit of a stupid question on my part. That's clever, thank you! And thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to work with Benjamin's suggestion (thank you!) and used a variable as a counter and a collection for the destinations. With the counter (starting at 0, as collections start with index 0) I can match the correct new agent with its corresponding destination.